# Streaming solution for video and audio

Tags: linux, media-server

I have some usb disks attached to my home-made router (ArchLinux) and I'm wondering what I could use to stream both **different** video and audio, to **different** nodes within the LAN, at the same time, from those network-attached disks.

The router itself is headleass (as a router should be), and your solution should have a friendly interface to use for both windows and linux machines, preferably via a web interface.

The idea is to reduce and to streamline data transfer between the router and the other nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two apps I have had most success with are [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) and [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/).

MediaTomb is specifically designed for low-end, linux-based kit and I run it on  D-Link DNS-323 NAS. Serviio runs on one of my CentOS servers with the NAS mounted on it via SMB.

The bonus with Serviio is that it works with Sony Bravia TVs, which are extremely fussy about with which media servers they will communicate.

MediaTomb has a Web interfaces (although it's not that elegant) and Serviio uses a Java client that can run on the server or on another remote box - I run mine on a netbook (Fedora 14) and a PC (Windows XP) on the LAN.

Both media server apps will also happily stream audio to my Android phone and the [2Player](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/music_and_audio/2player-network-music-player_mzkl.html) Android App works as a remote control allowing me to send audio to my Bravia TV from the Serviio server. I also have no probs streaming to VLC running on Windows or Linux and Movie Player (Linux)